# difference between qt and qnorm

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, econometrics

Can you tell me what is the difference between qt and qnorm?

From my understanding, qt is used for small sample, and qnorm is use for large sample. Am I correct?

If yes, how do I know whether my samples are large or small?

Thank you.

Comment: `qt` (in R) is a CDF of t distribution and `qnorm` of Normal distribution. How do you want to use this distribution functions for samples?

Answer (score 8):

`qt` returns quantiles (inverse cdf) of the t-distribution if you specify the tail area (left, by default) and degrees of freedom, while `qnorm` returns quantiles (inverse cdf) of the standard normal distribution.

Each are used for a wide variety of purposes, though you could use it for calculating critical values. However, it would be more typical to use `pt` or `pnorm` to compute p-values instead; indeed `t.test` and `summary.lm` and so on calculate the p-value for you.

> From my understanding, qt is used for small sample, and qnorm is use for large sample.

Well, no, not really. If you're doing a t-test there's simply *no good reason* to use normal functions like `qnorm` instead of t-functions like `qt` to obtain a critical value even at a very large sample size. What benefit in using something that may or may not be an adequate approximation when you have the t-calculation right there?

There are times when you would use `qnorm` -- for example, when you have an asymptotic normal approximation but *don't* have a t-distribution.

Answer (score -2):

Thumb rule is for $n$ greater than 30, you can assume normality. But that might not always be useful. For symmetric data, even smaller sample would do. For highly skewed data, you need larger sample. Plot your data. Look at the histogram. Is it symmetric? Fat tail? Based on these, take your call.

Comment: Furthermore more, when the standard deviation is unknown and needs to be estimated from the sample.